# How long should I quarantine items contaminated with the HSV-1 Virus (Cold Sore)?

Tags: virus, contaminate, cold-sores

I wanted to know how long does the HSV-1 virus lasts on, say, a tube of lip-balm?

The reason I ask is I believe I gave myself a new cold sore by using a tube of lip balm that I had last used when I had a cold sore (about 3 weeks previously) but I'm unsure if the surface can stay infected for that long.

I only seem to be able to find information about how long cold sores are contagious when experiencing a "break out" online - e.g. [MedicalNewsToday](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326350.php)

Comment: A capped tube of lip balm is a moist, dark environment. It wouldn't surprise me if some pathogens can survive quite a long time in such a place.

Comment: @Carey that's what I suspected